# Hive Window functions across multiple date ranges

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table that looks something like the below:

```
TagName | DateTime          | Value

TagName1|2016-07-06 09:49:34|14
TagName1|2016-07-06 09:50:34|15
TagName1|2016-07-06 09:51:34|18
TagName2|2016-07-03 02:13:34|421
TagName2|2016-07-03 03:13:34|422
TagName3|2016-07-01 03:13:34|14
```

What I am looking to do is multiple aggregate's on this table for each TagName (ex. sum, weighted avg, latest value, count, etc) for a defined date range.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
t1.TagName,
reflect("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID") as rv_id,
t2.item_id as rs_id,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as tstamp,
t1.datetime as last_date,
t1.value as last_value,
t1.minimum as minimum,
t1.maximum as maximum,
t1.count as count,
t1.total as total,
t1.average as average,
SUM(t1.weight_value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as weighted_average,
t1.Rank as Rank
FROM
(SELECT
TagName,
value,
datetime,
MIN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as minimum,
MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as maximum,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY datetime DESC) as Rank,
SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as total,
COUNT(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as count,
AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as average,
(unix_timestamp(datetime) - LAG(unix_timestamp(datetime),1) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY datetime))/
(SUM(unix_timestamp(datetime) - LAG(unix_timestamp(datetime),1) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY datetime)) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName)) * 
(LAG(value,1) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY datetime)) as weight_value
FROM raw.analog_history_dynamic
WHERE par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 5),'yyyyMMdd')) t1
LEFT JOIN meta.item_meta t2
ON t1.TagName = t2.name) t3
WHERE t3.Rank =1;
```

In this case I am looking at the last 5 days

```
WHERE par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 5),'yyyyMMdd'))
```

In addition to just 5 days, I have 10 other ranges I have a number of other ranges I need to calculate on:

```
-- 1min
WHERE par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 1),'yyyyMMdd')
and unix_timestamp(datetime) > unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) - 60000;   

-- 5Min
WHERE par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 1),'yyyyMMdd')
and unix_timestamp(datetime) > unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) - 300000;

-- 10 Min
WHERE par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 1),'yyyyMMdd')
and unix_timestamp(datetime) > unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) - 600000;

-- 30 Min
WHERE par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 1),'yyyyMMdd')
and unix_timestamp(datetime) > unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) - 1800000;

-- 1 Month
WHERE par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 30),'yyyyMMdd');

-- 2 Month
WHERE par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 60),'yyyyMMdd');
```

At the minimum I think I would want to combine the ones under the same partition so all the < 1 day aggregates (tables partitioned by date)

Any ideas or suggestions on being able to combine all these calculations within one query rather than performing each one individually with a different where condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
In the select query statement only you could use "case when condition;s" which you have given in where clause eg - 

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
t1.TagName,
reflect("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID") as rv_id,
t2.item_id as rs_id,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as tstamp,
t1.datetime as last_date,
t1.value as last_value,
t1.flag,
t1.minimum as minimum,
t1.maximum as maximum,
t1.count as count,
t1.total as total,
t1.average as average,
SUM(t1.weight_value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as weighted_average,
t1.Rank as Rank
FROM
(SELECT
TagName,
value,
datetime,
case 
when par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 1),'yyyyMMdd')
and unix_timestamp(datetime) > unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) - 60000 
then flag_1min
when par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 1),'yyyyMMdd')
and unix_timestamp(datetime) > unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) - 300000 
then flag_5min 
when .......and so on 
end as flag,
MIN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as minimum,
MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as maximum,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY datetime DESC) as Rank,
SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as total,
COUNT(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as count,
AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName) as average,
(unix_timestamp(datetime) - LAG(unix_timestamp(datetime),1) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY datetime))/
(SUM(unix_timestamp(datetime) - LAG(unix_timestamp(datetime),1) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY datetime)) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName)) * 
(LAG(value,1) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY datetime)) as weight_value
FROM raw.analog_history_dynamic
WHERE par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 5),'yyyyMMdd')) t1
LEFT JOIN meta.item_meta t2
ON t1.TagName = t2.name
group by TagName,
value,
datetime,
case 
when par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 1),'yyyyMMdd')
and unix_timestamp(datetime) > unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) - 60000 
then flag_1min
when par_date > date_format(date_sub(to_date(current_date), 1),'yyyyMMdd')
and unix_timestamp(datetime) > unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) - 300000 
then flag_5min 
when .......and so on 
end as flag,) t3
WHERE t3.Rank =1; 

NOTE: in the above code of yours, you have forgotten to use GROUP BY function since you had aggregate functions
```

Comment: I dont think GROUP BY is needed since all my aggregates are OVER PARTITION which groups by itself. It throws errors when you try to group by in original